# Click this link if you are not redirected automatically?

Tags: javascript, php

Why all(?) websites show this message to the user?

In my case I am using the following code:

```
<?php
    header('Refresh: 1; url=http://wikipedia.org');
?>

<!-- google analytics code -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        window.location.replace('http://wikipedia.org');
    };
</script>
```

The user will be redirected with javascript immediately after google analytics loads.

If this fails because the user has javascript off then he/she will be redirected after 1 second thanks to PHP.

If the analytics code takes more than 1 second, the tracking fails but we prevent user frustration because he/she waits only 1 second.

**My question is**: Why other sites show this message to the user? It's confusing to see a message and not read it because it's shown 100ms.

Given my code above, is there any case both of the redirection methods fail?

Comment: Most sites that show this leave the message up for about 5 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, I see. Is there any case both if my redirection methods fail?

Comment: I don't think so. The header should always be obeyed.

Comment: Did you get to know why some websites do this? What are some reasons that automatic javascript redirection might fail? Is it only in case javascript is disabled?